# Integer values for plt.xticks in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to plot a figure, and I set the plt.xticks as np.linspace(1, 3, 10).

I thought the values on the x-axis would be 1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, ..., 3.

But it turned out: 1.000, 1.222, 1.444, 1.667, ..., 3.000.

How can I fix this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_c = 1
n_s = np.linspace(1, 3, 100)

iso_trapping_efficiency = (np.sqrt(1 - (n_c ** 2 / n_s ** 2))) *100

plt.figure()
plt.plot(n_s, iso_trapping_efficiency, 'r', label='Isotropic Dipole')

plt.xlabel('Refractive Index, n_s', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Trapping Efficiency [%]', fontsize=15)

# change the xticks
plt.xticks(np.linspace(1, 3, 10))

plt.legend(loc='lower right')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `plt.xticks(np.linspace(1, 3, 11))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.linspace(1, 3, 10)` creates 10 samples (interval boundaries) in the interval `(1,3)`. Note that it includes beginning and end of the interval in the samples. Therefore, 10 samples of interval boundaries will create 10-1=9 intervals (think of it as a single interval has two boundaries). If you need to split it into 10 intervals, call `np.linspace` for 10+1 samples:

```
 np.linspace(1, 3, 11)
```

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter of `np.linspace()` does not include the value. Try `plt.xticks(np.linspace(1, 3, 11))`

Answer (score 1):

I think that matplotlib has some useful methods to do this. You could give a try to this one:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker # new line

n_c = 1
n_s = np.linspace(1, 3, 100)

iso_trapping_efficiency = (np.sqrt(1 - (n_c ** 2 / n_s ** 2))) *100

plt.figure()
plt.plot(n_s, iso_trapping_efficiency, 'r', label='Isotropic Dipole')

plt.xlabel('Refractive Index, n_s', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Trapping Efficiency [%]', fontsize=15)

# change the xticks
plt.xticks(np.linspace(1, 3, 10))

ax = plt.gca() # get current axis
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1.00)) # define a major locator to the ticker
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(0.25)) # set minor locators, w/o labels

plt.legend(loc='lower right')

plt.show()
```

The documentation of mpl is very good, it's filled with examples, you can check it out here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-formatters.html

Here's the result of the code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Python has default precision set for float variables. What you're looking for is rounding up just one variable.

```
plt.xticks(np.linspace(1, 3, 10).round(2))
```

Just adding round 2 solves the issue

Comment: No, this does not output what OP is looking for.